# mysql - Using Concat In Stored Procedure Dynamic Query

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, concatenation

To do point, I have simple query like

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE concat(firstName, ' ', lastName) in ('Adan Jack');
```

Query above run smoothly. But how if I combine that condition using Dynamic Query that using concat before?
I did this:

```
BEGIN
set @cond = concat(concat("firstName"," ", "lastName"), " in ('Adan Jack')";
set @query = concat("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ", @cond);
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

But no result and cause error.
Thanks.

Comment: I disagree with your query.  I think it should be this: `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE firstName = 'Adan' AND lastName = 'Jack'`.

Comment: There's a missing `)` at the end of `set @cond`.

Comment: @Raissa, user-defined variables like `@cond` and `@query` are scoped to your session, not to the procedure.  This means you can `SELECT @cond, @query;` on the same connection after the procedure is run, even if it fails, and examine the values you assigned to them.  This is useful for troubleshooting.

Comment: But also, @TimBiegeleisen is correct.  You should not write this query the way you have written it, because even though it will appear to work now, it will not be satisfactory, later, because it is very inefficient.  The query you have written requires every row of the entire table to be scanned, every time the query is run.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for advice :)